# How do you do a loop that can go through an entire column in an excel workbook and search for all instances of a string?

Tags: vba, excel

Im an intern at a company where they do a lot of DCR and Inductance readings and have all the values on text files. Ive managed to use VBA to import those text files into an excel spreadsheet however now I need to start manipulating that data. I'm trying to write some code that will loop through an entire column and search for the string "**DCR" and then give me the data that is in the cell offset (1,3), copy, and then paste it to a different range within the same workbook. I've written code where is searches for the first instance of the string and then copies and pastes that data that I need into the range, but then it stops there. The Do Loop code that I wrote gives me an infinite loop and doesnt work. Here is my code so far.

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim strSearch As String
strSearch = "**DCR"

Set rng1 = Range("A:A").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    rng1.Offset(1, 3).Copy
    Range("N11").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("O11").Select
    Do
        Set rng1 = Range("A:A").FindNext(rng1)
    Loop
End If

End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing and/or doing wrong. Thank you very much!

Comment: Refer this link http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: have you considered using formulas instead of macros? (i.e. VLOOKUP or Index + Match)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Const DCR As String = "**DCR"

Dim rngSearch As Range
Set rngSearch = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")

Dim rngFoundFirst As Range

Set rngFoundFirst = rngSearch.Find(DCR, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
' Anything found?
If Not rngFoundFirst Is Nothing Then
    Call ProcessDcr(rngFoundFirst)

    Dim rngFoundNext As Range
    Set rngFoundNext = rngFoundFirst

    Do
        Set rngFoundNext = rngSearch.FindNext(rngFoundNext)

        ' If first one is found, stop looping.
        If Not rngFoundNext Is Nothing Then
            If rngFoundNext.Address = rngFoundFirst.Address Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            Call ProcessDcr(rngFoundNext)
        End If
    Loop Until rngFoundNext Is Nothing
End If

Set rngFoundNext = Nothing
Set rngFoundFirst = Nothing
Set rngSearch = Nothing

End Sub

Sub ProcessDcr(rngFound As Range)

Call rngFound.Offset(1, 3).Copy
Call Range("N11").PasteSpecial(Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move the Do-Loop: basically loop as long as there are results to be found, quit when no result is found. But the code will still loop, cause findNext will continue to find the next result, even if it has already found it. So you have to keep to keep track of your first result.

You'll probably want to increment the location to which you copy.

Keep in mind that copy and paste is expensive in excel, a better and faster way is to copy the cell value.

```
       Dim strSearch As String
       Dim rng1 As Excel.Range
       Dim firstrng1 As Excel.Range
       Dim rowNumber as Integer
       rowNumber = 11;
       strSearch = "**DCR"

       Set rng1 = Range("A:A").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
       If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

       Set firstrng1 = rng1
       Do
          Range("N" & rowNumber).Value = rng1.Offset(1, 3)
          rowNumber = rowNumber + 1   
          Set rng1 = Range("A:A").FindNext(rng1)
          If rng1.Address = firstrng1.Address Then Exit Do
       Loop
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. The code is now looping through the entire first column. However I should've been more clear about this & I apologize but I want the code to go through the entire column and wherever it finds the string "**DCR" I want it to copy and paste that information starting with cell N11. The second time that **DCR appears I want it to copy and past it to the next cell down. so N12 etc. What its doing right now is its looping through it and it goes all the way to the end and only finds that value of the final DCR and pastes that onto cell N11.

Comment: What I need to do is end up with a column of DCR results starting on N11 and paste the next data on N12, then N13, N14 etc. Once again sorry for not making that clear in the beginning.

Comment: Easy enough (see my remark on the second paragraph). Please increase the score of this answer if this version solves your problem.

Comment: For a more efficient solution also keep in mind my third remark.